# QGIS 3.14 Set attribute of vector layer based on color of raster layer

Tags: qgis

I am using QGIS 3.14.

I am working with a raster layer and a vector layer. The Vector layer is a shapefile, and the raster layer is a PDF. I have them over laid on my map and I want to set an attribute on the vector layer based on the color of the raster layer underneath the individual shapes of the layer.

Can you point me to a knowledge base article, or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Check this https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html?highlight=raster#raster-value